# (ASM) Error when moving a byte to a pointer

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm, mov

I am having a problem with a line of assembly that I don't know how to solve.

```
mov byte ptr Label+ 2, f0h
```

I am trying to move the byte 0xF0 to the location Label + 2. When I try to move a byte it fails, but when I try to move a dword, it works.
Whenever I try to compile the program, it gives the following error:

```
A2006   undefined symbol : f0h
```

I am using visual studio syntax, so (as far as I know) I should be using F0h instead of 0xF0.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Use `0F0h` since numbers must begin with a digit.

Comment: (The answers on the linked duplicate cover plain MASM as well as inline asm.)